# Get multiple columns data from extra query in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models as below:

```
class Model1(models.model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Model2(models.model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I would like to get the related `model2` which have the same column value in `filename` as that of `model1`.

My solution was to use either `Subquery` or `Extra`. The problem with `Subquery` is that it allows only one column to be queried but what I want is a dict object of all the columns of `model2` related to `model1`. They **do not** have a `foreignkey` relation to use `select_related`. So I tried to use `extra` but again I am getting the multiple columns error. How can I solve this problem?

My code is as below:

```
model1_objs = Model1.objects.filter(id=given_id).extra(
    select={
        "model2_obj": f"SELECT * 
                        FROM model2 
                        WHERE filename = model1.filename 
                        AND id = '{model2_id}'"
    }
)
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be as efficient as the solution you were thinking of but you could try this:

```py
model1_obj = Model1.objects.get(id=given_id)
model2_objs = Model2.objects.filter(filename=model1_obj.filename)
```

Note: consider using the get() method to fetch unique objects
Have a look at this: [Making queries (Django documentation)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use this method then again I have to loop through both querysets and merge them based on the filename. My final output should be of this form: `[{"model1_obj": model1fields, models2_obj: {model2fields}}], ...`. So every item in this list will be a nested dictionary. I was trying of a way to do this without looping.